# React Leaflet key warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I have a function that iterates through an array, grabs all of the marker data then places them in a Map component. React keeps warning me that each child should have a key. Leaflet generates additional children for each marker. I do not have any control over those additional children.

Here is that section of code

```html
{
  this.state.markers.map((content, idx) => (
    <>
      <Marker
        key={`marker-${idx}`}
        icon={content["icon"]}
        position={content["position"]}
      >
        <Popup
          key={`popup-${idx}`}
          closeButton={false}
          className={styles.popup}
        >
          <span>{content["popupText"]}</span>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
      {content["radius"] && (
        <Circle
          key={`circle-${idx}`}
          center={content["position"]}
          radius={content["radius"]}
          color={content["color"]}
        ></Circle>
      )}
    </>
  ));
}
```

The array of markers is generated by a function that grabs data from firebase.

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('markers').get().then(async (snap) => {
    snap.forEach((marker) => {
        this.state.markers.push({
            position: marker.data()['position'],
            icon: this.state.icons[marker.data()['icon']][0],
            color: this.state.icons[marker.data()['icon']][1],
            popupText: marker.data()['popupText'],
            radius: marker.data()['radius']
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React keys need to be on the outer node returned from the mapping function, and they can't be added to the fragment shorthand, it needs to be an actual component. The other keys using in the nested components aren't serving any purpose as far as react is concerned so you can likely remove them.

[Lists & Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```
{
  this.state.markers.map((content, idx) => (
    <Fragment key={/* some unique key value */}> // <-- use key here!
      <Marker
        key={`marker-${idx}`}
        icon={content["icon"]}
        position={content["position"]}
      >
        <Popup
          key={`popup-${idx}`}
          closeButton={false}
          className={styles.popup}
        >
          <span>{content["popupText"]}</span>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
      {content["radius"] && (
        <Circle
          key={`circle-${idx}`}
          center={content["position"]}
          radius={content["radius"]}
          color={content["color"]}
        />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  ));
}
```

*Note: It also isn't recommended to use the array index as part of the key unless you ***know*** the array is stable, i.e. no adds/removals and re-orderings between renders.*

Comment: wow the fragment. i could never guess that. thank you kind stranger

Comment: @clandestine Yeah, it's certainly a good gotcha. Cheers.